# HTML5 audio duration using jQuery

Tags: html

I am trying to get the audio duration using jQuery but having hard time getting it. The method I am using is defined below

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');            
        audioElement.setAttribute('src','song.mp3');            
           audioElement.play();
           var duration = audioElement.duration;
               $(".songtime").html(duration);
```

But it says `nan` Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: There's no jQuery there, and since you haven't even set a source for the audio, how do you expect it to have a duration?! Does it really say `nan`? `NaN` seems more likely.

Comment: var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');   audioElement.setAttribute('src','song.mp3');    audioElement.play();
var duration = audioElement.duration;
$(".songtime").html(duration);  does it looks fine

Comment: @mat:- that's kk mat but again i never want to be aggressive just want some help and it can happen that i was wrong in explaining question , and a person can politely lemme know

Answer (score 10):

Since the audio isn't still loaded, you need to wait until your element has the metadata loaded, there is a simple way to do it:

```
audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
    var duration = audioElement.duration;
    //TODO whatever
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably issue is not valid any more but issue is that audio doesnt load file yet.
You should add event when file is loaded

```
 $(audioElement).on("canplay", function () {
        alert(this.duration);
    });
```

Comment: Finally worked for me!! Thanks. My problem was that the .duration wasn't applying to jQuery objects, just plain JS.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to read the duration before the audio file has been loaded. You have to wait until the browser knows what the duration is (i.e. after it has had time to download the file header).

Comment: yup i did ,.. it's not even reading it at all.. i tried to wait for couple of minutes

Comment: It isn't reading the file at all? But you said it was playing the audio, it has to read the file to do that.

Comment: it's not getting the time at all i mean.... audio is playing fine letting me change the volume ... getting current time as well but not the actual duration ...

Comment: After adding a delay before reading the duration, it worked for me. Perhaps you are using an audio format with an unknown duration (streaming audio for example).

Comment: I'm having this same problem w/ JQuery 1.7 but not pre 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Others have had this issue and it looks like Safari can get thrown off if your web server does not send the proper HTTP header tags. I am having the same issue -- my demo was loading and playing the audio just fine but the duration always returned 'infiniti' due to the http headers my local server was using to serve the mp3 file.

The basic gist is that the content-type should be as follows:

```
Content-Type:audio/mpeg; name="name_of_file.mp3"
```

Instead of:

```
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
```

For more info see the original post here:
http://groups.google.com/group/jplayer/browse_thread/thread/256d29fcc158f8ec