# Need to get audio timing in alert box

Tags: html

```
<audio id="audio1" controls>
   <source src="audio/audio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   <source src="audio/audio2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
 <embed height="50" width="100" src="audio/audio2.mp3">
```

I just want to get 
  1.Duration of the audio file.
  2.the timing of audio file when i press pause..

please state me answer in javascript or jquery

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious why you rolled back your question to the original version? I took my time to fix your grammar and better format the question, only for you to revert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

1. Use [loadedmetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13114094/897326) or [canplay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298062/897326) events of the audio element.
2. Use [timeupdate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381794/897326) event of the audio element.