# How to get current duration of audio file using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a audio player who can give me current duration of audio file. Actually i want to show  different html on every duration who will give me that player. Please someone help me.

Comment: I want to make a mp3 player with lyrics. the lyrics text will not only a text it would be a combination of html and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly are You trying to do, but You can take a look at this nice example of everything.
http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/VvmmC/

```
 i
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear, you give me the thing what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/13114094

```
//audioElement is your audio element
audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
    var duration = audioElement.duration;
    //TODO whatever
});
```